# T-test or Wilcoxon for small sample paired data

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have metabolomics data, I only have 5 paired samples. the data does not follow a normal distribution so instead of doing a t test I was thinking of doing Mann Whitney Wilcoxon (MWW) test but I have read that for the MWW test the data has to be independent and this is not the case. Which test can I use?

Thank you

Comment: You are not stating what exactly you want to know. With 5 pairs the power of any test will be very low, so it may not make sense to run any test. The paired t-test could give some indication in case the data are not too non-normal. How do you know your data "do not follow a normal distribution"? What indication against normality do you have? And why do you need a test?

Comment: I have around 400 metabolites for 5 paired samples (before and after a treatment) and want to know which metabolites are different before and after treatment. I know the data es not normal because of the plots and the shapiro test showed the data es not normal. I was thinking maybe about transforming the data...

Comment: Does that mean you ran 400 Shapiro tests and looked at 400 plots? In any case, note that if you run 400 tests, there will be random significances. Only Bonferroni-corrected p-values (i.e., significant at 0.05/400) give a clear indication that a specific metabolite is different in such a situation. Given that with $n=5$ the power of any test is very weak, I don't see that you can get a single p-value of this kind. So chances are significance testing will not address this issue appropriately. You'd need more data.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main issues (independence, normality, and sample size), which I would like to
address separately--to the extent possible.

**Independence.** If you are doing a paired test, you are essentially doing
a one-sample test on the difference in values for each pair. Both the one-sample
t test and one-sample [Wilcoxon (signed-rank) test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) require that the differences
are randomly sampled from a population, and hence that differences are
independent of one another. (Of course, the two observations that yielded the
differences for each pair are not independent, but that is an issue.)

**Normality.** The t test requires normal data in order to give accurate results.
The Wilcoxon test does not require normal data. However, for straightforward interpretation of results, it is best that the differences be symmetrically
distributed. (There are several measures of 'location', mostly all giving the same
result for symmetrical data.)  From small samples alone, it can be difficult to
know whether data are normal.

Sometimes prior knowledge about the kind of data
at hand can be an important clue. In particular, standard tests of normality have poor power detecting non-normality in small samples. Looking at boxplots and normal probability plots can give useful, but subjective, impressions.

The difference between two exponential distributions with equal rate has a [Laplace distribution,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) which is symmetrical, but far from normal because of fat tails--both left and right.
The following simulation in R shows that, among Laplace samples of size $n=10,$ the Shapiro-Wilk test detects non-normality with probability only about $0.15.$

```
set.seed(818)
pv = replicate(10^5, shapiro.test(rexp(10)-rexp(10))$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.15156
```

**Sample size.** You say you have only $n=5$ pairs. With a sample of size five,
a two-sided Wilcoxon test can never give a P-value below $1/16 = 0.0625 > 5\%.$
A one-sided Wilcoxon test gives P-value $1/32 = 0.03125 < 5\%,$ only if all five paired differences have the
same sign (as appropriate to the direction of the alternative).

```
wilcox.test(1:5, alt="greater")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  1:5
V = 15, p-value = 0.03125
alternative hypothesis: true location is greater than 0
```

Suppose that data are five differences from a Laplace distribution with center at $\mu=\eta=3$ and variance 2. Notice that the effect is relatively large.

Below are results from a one-sided t test (inappropriate
because data are not normal). The power against this large effect is
about $96\%.$ For a Wilcoxon signed-rank test, power is about $0.88.$

```
set.seed(2020)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rexp(5)-rexp(5)+3, alt="greater")$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.96265

pv = replicate(10^5, wilcox.test(rexp(5)-rexp(5)+3, alt="greater")$p.val)
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.88063
```

The actual significance level of the one-sided test (when $\mu=\eta=0),$ at a nominal $5\%$ level, is about $3\%$ (Laplace data are far from normal, so the t statistic doesn't have a Student t distribution). For Wilcoxon, the actual significance level is about $4\%$ (the test statistic for $n=6$ is highly discrete). [R code is the same, except omit the `+3`s.]

**Tentative conclusion.** Of course, results for your (presumably non-Laplace) data may be quite different. However, if you have a large effect and if it is appropriate to do one-sided tests,
you might get useful results using a Wilcoxon signed-rank test on paired differences.

Answer (score 1):

If you were inclined to do a ttest but the assumptions of normality aren't met (but the data points are independent and exchangeable) you can still do a permutation test. Its the non-parametric analog to the ttest that doesn't care about the distribution of the data. Here is a shell of the code to do that:

```
rm(list=ls(all=T))
set.seed(1)

#import the data
setwd('')## set your working directory here
dat=read.csv('',as.is=T)## call in your data in csv format here

#calculate the mean 
tmp=aggregate(variable~sample,data=dat,mean)
#calculate the difference in means 
obs.stat=tmp$variable[1]-tmp$variable[2] #this is our observed statistic
n=nrow(dat) #total number of observations

nsim=1000 #total number of simulations (i.e., randomizations)
sim.stat=rep(NA,nsim) #empty vector to store the simulated statistic from our randomizations

for (i in 1:nsim){ #do this shuffling "nsim" times
  print(i)
  
  prod=sample(dat$sample) # mix 

  #create a new dataset 
  dat.new=data.frame(variable=dat$variable,sample=prod) 
  #calculate mean based on this new dataset
  dat.new1=aggregate(variable~sample,data=dat.new,mean) 
  #calculate the difference in means based on this new dataset
  sim.stat[i]=dat.new1$variable[1]-dat.new1$variable[2] #store the simulated statistic
}

#create a histogram of the simulated statistics. 
#This is the distribution of our test statistic under the null hypothesis (i.e., null distribution)
hist(sim.stat,main='Simulated difference in means',xlab='') 

#is the observed test statistic likely to have come from this null distribution?
abline(v=obs.stat,col='red') 

#what proportion of simulated statistics was smaller than the observed statistic?
vec=sim.stat < obs.stat #query: is sim.stat smaller than obs.stat?
mean(vec) #proportion of simulations that satisfy the above query. This is the p-value of our randomization test.

#Notice that numbers close to 0 or close to 1 indicate extreme outcomes.
#For instance, a p-value of 0.999 indicates that almost all of the simulated statistics were
#smaller than the observed statistic. As a result, this suggests that we can reject the 
#null hypothesis even though our p-value was greater than the threshold of 0.05.
```

If something like this is what you are after, I am happy to clarify anything if you get stuck.

Good luck,
E123